# Nested list indexing

Tags: python, nested-lists

Trying to create program to answer this question:

> [ ] The `records` list contains information about some company's employees
>   each of the elements in `records` is a list containing the name and ID of an employee.
>   Write a program that prompts the user for a name and return the ID of the employee if a record is found
>
> records = [['Colette', 22347], ['Skye', 35803], ['Alton', 45825], ['Jin', 24213]]

This is my code, so far:

```
ui = input('Enter employee name: ')

for row in records:
    if row[0] in ui:
        print(row[1])
    else:
        print('Employee not found!')

    ui = input('Enter employee name: ')
```

I cannot seem to find a way to check if 'ui' is in the records list.

Comment: What about `if row[0] == ui:`. Also you need to stop the loop when you find it.

Comment: it must be a list? A dictionary would be a better approach I think

Comment: Tried row[0] == ui: still not working

Comment: every thing is good except last string in your code. comment him and you will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
records = [['Colette', 22347], ['Skye', 35803], ['Alton', 45825], ['Jin', 24213]]
user_name = 'colette' # User input

for i in range(0,len(records)):
    # Here I make User name and Name in Recored in lower case so it can match perfectly
    if user_name.lower() in records[i][0].lower():
        print(records[i])
    else:
        print("employee not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Associate the else block with the for loop instead of the if statement

```
ui = input('Enter employee name: ')
for row in records:
    if row[0] == ui:
        print(row[1])
        break
else:
    print('Employee not found!')
```

But, if you convert the nested list to a dict, it would be much easier to get the 'id'

```
ui = input('Enter employee name: ')
d = dict(records)
print(d.get(ui, 'Employee not found!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to do it -

```
[i for i in records if ui in i]
```

This will give you a list of list of employee you are trying to find else empty list.

For ex-

`ui = 'Colette'`

O/P -

```
[['Colette', 22347]]
```

You could do something like -

```
ui = input('Enter employee name: ')
found = [i for i in records if ui in i]
if found:
    for emp in found:
        print(emp[1])
else:
    print("Employee not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of it, **Do keep in mind when comparing two strings, python doesn't automatically convert uppercase to lowercase so its important if you intend to compare a string that you convert both the string in either lower or uppercase**

```
records = [['Colette', 22347], ['Skye', 35803], ['Alton', 45825], ['Jin', 24213]]
ui = str.lower(input('Enter employee name: '))

names_to_compare=[t[0].lower() for t in records]

if ui in names_to_compare:
    print(records[names_to_compare.index(ui)][1])

else:
    print("Employee not in records")
```

Comment: Thanks Inder. note taken about case sensitivity.